# How to 'get' another Model field on ExtJS 5.1.1

Tags: extjs, renderer, gridpanel

I'm trying to use `renderer` config inside Ext.column. I have two fields states in Model; `balanceok` and `lastbalance`. But it gives this error:

```
[W] XTemplate evaluation exception: getRecord is not defined
```

How I can display another field with `get` method?

**Model**:

```
Ext.define('MultiDB.model.FolioModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'clientname', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'balanceok', type: 'bool'},
        {name: 'lastbalance', type: 'int'}
    ]
```

**Grid Panel**:

```
{
  dataIndex: 'balanceok',
  flex: 1,
  text: 'Balance',
  renderer: function (value, record, store) {
     if (value == 1) {
        return "All Paid";
     } else {
        return getRecord('lastbalance');
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you found `getRecord`, the correct call would be:

```
record.get('lastbalance');
```

As a side note, the check for `value == 1` is a little odd since the field will be casted to a boolean because of the model.

Comment: Hello again @evan-trimboli . Your reply has worked easily and i just changed `getRecord` to `record.get` . Answer for your first question is **Stackoverflow**. Before asking a question, I'm deep diving to here and trying all sample code blocks. If it's still not working, then I am posting question. And please read the comment below I've posted to @djmm187 to understand that *odd situation* you've noticed. =) Thanks a lot!

Comment: By specifying the `type` in the model definition, it means that the value coming from the server is converted to a boolean value, so it's `true/false`. That means your check would just be: `if (balanceok)`

Comment: So far It's mistake to assign field type as `bool`. Then what would be more feasible for my situation? There is only `0` and `1` for server response! Is it ok if I'll assign it to `int`? --*Well, I've tried and it works w/out any problem for now!*

Answer (score 3):

Renderer already provides a record argument. You can use getRecord when focusing on a grid cell, but it looks like you do not need this from the use case described above.

It looks like you have the renderer arguments a little off, which may be why you are having an issue checking and retrieving the value.

If you update your column renderer from:

 `renderer: function (value, record, store) { ... }`

to:

`renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) { ... }`

You can see a full description of render method here:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer

Take a look at the fiddle below for a working example that will help get you going:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/251r

Comment: Dear @djmm187 thanks for your reply. I've checked the fiddle and implemented but it did not work as you created so I had to change a few things. The reason is `balanceok` field is response as 0 or 1 from server. So the demo that i've created is behavior as: *if it's 1 then "All Paid", else give me the `lastbalance`*. Thus i asked myself! Is it a mistake to assign 'bool' for `balanceok`?

Comment: hum.. javascript should implicitly eval 0,1 to False, True within the expression, along with extjs casting the model property to the assigned type (at least in this case). You can also see this with `checkboxfield` return types 0,1. But it wouldn't be a bad idea to update the model to be as explicit as possible. Explicit is always better than implicit. :)